# Class files are missing in code coverage result

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, c#-4.0, code-coverage

I have a number of classes in my project. When I check Code Coverage result after running the unit test cases, it does not show all the classes. I am not sure what are the criteria on which the code coverage process the class files.

I read somewhere that if you have not created the test cases for a class file in your Test project it will not be covered in the code coverage. But for me it does not seem true as I can see the the class files even though those are not in the test project.

Comment: are you talking about Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes in Visual Studio 4.0 code coverage result.

Comment: Do you have, or can you show, an example of the classes that aren't covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are couple of ways to exclude files from code coverage, most popular being an attribute:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
```

Comment: Some of my classes had this attribute and removed it from the classes but still it does not include my classes in code coverage result. I need them in code coverage result.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late in the day, but if you have a class that consists entirely of auto-properties, then this class won't be included in the code coverage stats.

**Included**

```
private int _seq;

public int InvoiceSequenceNumber 
{
    get
    {
        return _seq;
    }

    set
    {
        _seq = value;
    }
}
```

**Not included**

```
public int InvoiceSequenceNumber { get; set; }
```